# iMessage group members visibility

Tags: ios, messages, privacy, group

I'm curious how the group visibility works with iMessage.

I have a hunch that when sending with iMessage to a group of people, all these people will see each other in the group. Is my assumption correct?

However, if one of these people is not using iMessage then the message will be sent as a regular text message and the group members will not see each other in the group. Correct assumption?

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR
(1) Yes and (2) yes (but can be no depending on configuration).

1. If all the recipients are on iMessage, then it will be an entirely group thing. Everyone sees everyone, and everyone gets all replies.
2. If you have Group Messaging *disabled* under Settings.app > Messages > Group Messaging, then they will send as individual text - replies will be separate. If the carrier you are with doesn't provide group messaging there will **be no option** for Group Messaging. It is disabled by default.

---

Now, with the assumption that iMessage is *on* on your phone:

If you have Group Messaging *disabled* (or your carrier doesn't support it), then when you compose a text to two recipients (at least one off of iMessage) a thread, on your phone, called "OutGoing" will be created. It will then send out separate SMS messages to each user. Recipients won't be able to see who else you texted.

If you have Group Messaging enabled (note: MMS Messaging must be enabled for you to even see the "Group Messaging" option), and compose a text to two persons (at least one off of iMessage), then it will send a group text. Just like iMessage, everyone sees everyone, and everyone gets all replies. Again, the Group Messaging option will only be available if your carrier is compatible with the option. I believe AT&T and Verizon support Group Messaging. They may be the only ones.

Obviously, if everyone is on iMessage, like I stated above, everyone sees everyone, and everyone gets all replies.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I asked this question on another forum and that user states that I'm correct on both assumptions... https://discussions.apple.com/message/21182142?ac_cid=op123456#21182142

Comment: @PeterWarbo, very interesting. I just discovered the thing that both of us were missing (or at least he didn't tell you). This is where a setting comes in. Re-read my answer. I am confident this setting change is what is going on.

Comment: That is interesting indeed because my iPhone is missing the "Group Chat" option. Seems that it is a carrier option (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4735549?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: @PeterWarbo, well I really learned something through this. It is true that the the Group Messaging option would be a carrier dependency. Thank you for sticking this one out with me. I will edit my post so that future users can fully understand what the problem is. I would recommend you edit your question with details that you now know are relevant. Such as the carrier you are with, and any other details you may be able to provide like that.